# mod rewrite folder to folder on different server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the user but have the URL stay the same.
If I do this:

redirect 301 /folder/ http://mysite.com/folder/

It works but the URL in the browser changes.  Was wondering what the mod rewrite equivalent of the above redirect is so that the URL stays the same.  If this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule /folder http://mysite.com/folder [P,L]
```

You will also need `mod_proxy` enabled, as `[P]` is the Proxy flag.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is happening that it doesn't work? Is it redirecting the request at all?

Comment: No it's not redirecting at all.

Comment: I realized that I forgot to mention you will need `RewriteEngine On` prior to the `RewriteRule ..`

Comment: Are you putting the rule in the main apache config file or in a .htaccess file?  If it is in a .htaccess file you should try `RewriteRule folder http://mysite.com/folder [P,L]` .  Otherwise, can you turn on the `RewriteLog` and set the `RewriteLogLevel` to 3 or 4.  You should then be able to see what the URL is coming into apache as and why it doesn't match.

Comment: It's in .htaccess.  I changed it from /folder to folder and it redirects now.  But the URL changes in the address bar.  

I would like the the URL to stay the same in the address bar.  So it rewrites http://newsite.com/folder to http://mysite.com/folder but it should still display http://newsite.com/folder in the address bar.

Comment: That's interesting...the proxy flag shouldn't be redirecting the request.  Do you have other rewrite rules in place? Could you provide your full .htaccess file?

Comment: Oops, the problem was that mysite.com/folder redirects to another page on the mysite domain.  I tried it for another page and it works. Problem now is newsite.com/folder/* redirects to mysite.com/folder.  For example newsite.com/folder/child/file.txt goes to mysite.com/folder instead of mysite.com/folder/child/file.txt.  But I think I will be able to find the expression for that somewhere, if it exists.  Thank you for your continued assistance.

Comment: Your welcome.  Just in case you haven't found it yet, this will do the trick: `RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/$1 [P]`